# Are Alpine "stable" versions stable in the sense of keeping package versions the same?

Tags: alpine-linux

I'm looking for Alpine Linux's documented approach to keeping / upgrading individual package versions within a named stable Alpine version.

So assuming I'm building an image (such as docker) and I start with:

```
FROM alpine:3.13.1
RUN apk add python3 py3-numpy
```

Then...

1. is it safe to assume this will always install the same major / minor version of python3 and numpy.
2. will these receive security patches *(if I rebuild the image)*
3. How does (#1 and #2) differ if I only pin to say `3.13` instead of `3.13.1`.

Answer (score 1):

I’m not aware of any explicit documentation describing this, beyond the fact that [stable releases only get bug fixes](https://wiki.alpinelinux.org/wiki/Alpine_Linux:FAQ#What_is_the_difference_between_edge_and_stable_releases.3F):

> Stable releases are just what they sound like: initially a point-in-time snapshot of the package archives, but then maintained with bug-fixes only in order to keep a stable environment.

However, some experimentation shows that installations aren’t pinned to the patch release they are based on:

```
$ docker run -it --rm alpine:3.13.0
/ # apk add php8
fetch https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.13/main/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
fetch https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.13/community/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
(1/9) Installing php8-common (8.0.2-r0)
(2/9) Installing argon2-libs (20190702-r1)
(3/9) Installing ncurses-terminfo-base (6.2_p20210109-r0)
(4/9) Installing ncurses-libs (6.2_p20210109-r0)
(5/9) Installing libedit (20191231.3.1-r1)
(6/9) Installing pcre2 (10.36-r0)
(7/9) Installing xz-libs (5.2.5-r0)
(8/9) Installing libxml2 (2.9.10-r6)
(9/9) Installing php8 (8.0.2-r0)
Executing busybox-1.32.1-r0.trigger
OK: 13 MiB in 23 packages
/ #
```

— the indexes are for “v3.13”, and installing `php8` gives us 8.0.2, which is listed as part of [3.13.2](https://alpinelinux.org/posts/Alpine-3.13.2-released.html).

Further experimentation shows that:

- using `alpine:3.13` as a base image results in the latest patch release;
- using `alpine:3.13.x` as a base image results in that specific patch release for those packages which are part of the image (`musl`, `zlib`, `apk-toole` etc.), but installing anything will install the latest available version in the general release;
- you’d need `apk upgrade --available` anyway to ensure you pick up fixes to the core packages.

As a result, there doesn’t seem to be a way of ensuring that rebuilding your image will always yield the same set of packages and versions.

If you want to keep a consistent set of packages and versions, you can build and tag your own images (but then forgo security fixes).

Answer (score 1):

I've put a similar question to the Alpine Users mailing list and received [a response back from Natanael Copa](https://lists.alpinelinux.org/%7Ealpine/users/%3CC8402E24-B03E-4D8D-A907-57DE4C5E8865%40gmail.com%3E):

> > ...*snip*
>
> Yes. We provide security updates.
>
> > Will entirely new versions of packages get released?
>
> Depends a bit. We may update the package to a new version if it is
> unlikely that the update will break anything. We may backport the
> security fix with a patch.
>
> The goal is that you should be able to use a stable branch and not be
> afraid of doing `apk upgrade` to get security updates.
>
> > So if I start with alpine 3.12 and *apk add python3 py3-numpy*, is it
> > safe to assume that I will always get the same version of *numpy"
> > (notwithstanding security fixes)?
>
> At this stage, alpine 3.12 will only get security updates. So you will
> always get the same version unless there are security issues (or other
> major bugs are reported).
>
> alpine 3.13 may get bug fixes in addition to security fixes, but new
> versions are not automatically added to 3.13.
>
> In both cases, you are supposed to be able to `apk add python3 py3-numpy` and be safe that things does not break when you apk
> upgrade. We should not push API or ABI breaking changes to stable
> branches. (there have been a few exceptions ofc)

*At this time 3.13 is the latest.*